# Como importar um arquivo .xls no R mantendo os nomes com acentos nas variáveis categóricas?

Tags: r, codificação-de-caracteres, xls

Fiz a importação de um arquivo em .xls que contém colunas com nomes de drogas e sua classe. Alguns nomes têm acento como "Antipsicótico", "Benzodiazepínico" e "Antidepressivo Tricíclico". Usei o read.xlsx conforme abaixo:

```
require(xlsx)
AskStack <- read.xlsx("file.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1)
```

E quando chequei o data.frame vi que os nomes estavam com modificações de encoding conforme verão adiante:

```
> dput(AskStack)
structure(list(Medic.1 = structure(c(24L, 13L, 15L, 3L, 32L, 
9L, 2L, 17L, 15L, 21L, 25L, 32L, 17L, 21L, 9L, 9L, 15L, 15L, 
26L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 20L, 31L, 21L, 24L, 21L, 31L, 24L, 17L, 2L, 
32L, 31L, 23L, 26L, 25L, 31L, 11L, 31L, 12L), .Label = c("alprazolam", 
"Alprazolam", "Amitriptilina", "Bupropiona", "citalopram", "clomipramina", 
"clonazepam", "Clonazepam", "Desvenlafaxina", "Diazepam", "Donarem", 
"Donaren", "Duloxetina", "escitalopram", "Escitalopram", "fluoxetina", 
"Fluoxetina", "fluvoxamina", "imipramina", "Imipramina", "Olanzapina", 
"paroxetina", "Pondera", "Quetiapina", "Quetros", "Risperidona", 
"Rivotril", "Sem uso informado", "sertralina", "Trazodona", "Venlafaxina", 
"Venlaxin"), class = "factor"), classe = structure(c(2L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Antidepressivo TricÃ­clico", 
"AntipsicÃ³tico", "BenzodiazepÃ­nico", "ISRS", "ISRSN", "nÃ£o se aplica"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

> Como faço para importar sem a necessidade de alterar manualmente depois da importação?

Comment: Tente especificar o `enconding` na função `encoding = "UTF-8"`. Que o problema deve estar por aí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o pacote `readxl`, que resolve o problema automaticamente:

```
> library(readxl)
> read_xlsx("Drogas.xlsx")
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  Drogas                   
  <chr>                    
1 Antipsicótico            
2 Benzodiazepínico         
3 Antidepressivo Tricíclico
```

Eu particularmente prefiro o `readxl` para ler arquivos do excel em R.